# What does this daemonize method do?

Tags: python

I was looking around on GitHub, when I stumbled across this method called `daemonize()` in a reverse shell example. <sup>[source](https://gist.github.com/gdamjan/3025923)</sup>

What I don't quite understand is what it does in this context, wouldn't running this code from the command line as such: `python example.py &` not achieve the same thing?

Deamonize method source:

```
def daemonize():
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid > 0:
        sys.exit(0)   # Exit first parent
    pid = os.fork()
    if pid > 0:
        sys.exit(0)   # Exit second parent
```

Comment: See [What's the difference between running a program as a daemon and forking it into background with '&'?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56495/whats-the-difference-between-running-a-program-as-a-daemon-and-forking-it-into)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A background process - running `python2.7 <file>.py` with the `&` signal - is not the same thing as a true daemon process.

A true daemon process:

- Runs in the background. This also happens if you use `&`, and is where the similarity ends.
- Is not in the same process group as the terminal. When the terminal closes, the daemon will not die either. This does not happen with `&` - the process remains the same, it is simply moved to the background.
- Properly closes all inherited file descriptors (including input, output, etc.) so that nothing ties it back to the parent. Again, this does not happen with `&` - it will still write to the terminal.
- Should only ideally be killed by SIGKILL, not SIGHUP. Running with `&` allows your process to be killed by SIGHUP.

---

All of this, however, is pedantry. Few tasks really require you to go to the extreme that these properties require - a background task spawned in a new terminal using `screen` can usually do the same job, though less efficiently, and you may as well call that a daemon in that it is a long-running background task. The only real difference between *that* and a true daemon is that the latter simply tries to avoid all avenues of potential death.

The code you saw simply forks the current process. Essentially, it clones the current process, kills its parent and 'acts in the background' by simply being a separate process that does not block the current execution - a bit of an ugly hack, if you ask me, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Orphan Processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) and [Daemon Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computer_software%29). A process without a parent becomes a child of init (pid 1).

When it comes time to shut down a group of processes, say all the children of a bash instance, the OS will go about giving a sighup to the children of that bash. An orphan, forced as in this case, or other due to some accident, won't get that treatment and will stay around longer.